# How can I get failed test name in codeception

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I want to get failed test name in _failed event in ApiTester Codeception, How can I get that ?

```
    <?php
    public function _failed(ApiTester $I)
    {
        // When access token has expired I get new 
        // access token and I need to run failed test
        // with new access token
    }

    public function otherTest(ApiTester $I)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Have you got a way to restart failed test? I think that it would be better to check if the token is still valid in _before hook.